# Access to Vertex Normals in Geometry Nodes

Tags: normals, geometry-nodes

`vertex_normal` was a Mesh attribute, available in Blender 2.93's Geometry Nodes. It has since disappeared. The `normal` attribute is a face-normal, available in the Face domain.

It is often necessary to access the vertex-normal, for instance in a case like this:

[image]

.. where tiles are selected and rotated according to vertex normal.

At the moment, the only way I can find to get hold of vertex-mormals is to *Point Instance* sticky notes all over my mesh, and transfer their instance normals (which are not listed as available,) back into the mesh, as in `v_normal_B`, below:

[image]

Am I missing something? When the team removed `vertex_normal`, was it because there is a better way? Better still, is there a way of accessing custom normals?

Comment: If anybody knows the development well enough to know the general plan of attack.. whether this kind of attribute is likely to reappear, so much the better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try to get it like this:

[image]

Comment: Aaaargh! I've been ploughing through the docs to figure out how on earth I could have deduced this from them. Did you watch the same video as me? Well, I did :D . And the language seemed so.. well.. non-mathy, and the 'String' seemed not necessary.. so, when I tried it and it didn't work, I gave up instead of re-checking.

Comment: Yep, string is not necessary- might be I am watching tons of tutorials….

Comment: But I am happy I could at least one time help you

Answer (score 4):

Since Blender 3.0. there's <kbd>I</kbd>Input > <kbd>N</kbd>Normal node:

[image]

It will give a vertex normal if evaluated for a point domain, like here:
[geometry nodes - even thickness boundary](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/249051/60486)

Comment: I would tick this, but that would seem unfair on Chris.. his answer was right at the time. :)

Comment: @RobinBetts Chris'es answer is still valid for versions prior 3.0 which are and will be used for a long time.